# Добавить массив в базу и вывести его с помощью select

Tags: массивы, php, html, sql

Привет все.

Прошу прощения за тупизм.

Никогда не сталкивался с `multiple в select` вообще ни разу, и вот тут делая магазин понял что нужен список с возможностью выбора цветов при добавлении товара в базу.

Ну как я понял, нужно в `name` прописать типо `product_color[]` массив - вроде бы понятно, но вот как этот массив добавить в базу с перечислением всех цветов, а потом как это вывести в виде того же `select`?

Помогите вообще не представляю как сделать даже =/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/*предполагается, что защиту от XSS вы уже сделали*/

//Ввод данных на примере insert:
$sql = 'insert into colors_table (color) values ("'.implode('"),("',$_POST['product_color']).'")';

//Вывод данных:

select * from colors_table where color!="red";

//Получаете массив объектов при помощи, например, mysqli.

print('<select>');
foreach($rows as $row){

printf('<option value="%1$s">%1$s</option>',$row->color);

} 
print('</select>');
```

---

Тогда так.
1) таблица товары:

```
product_id, product_name, product_price //например
```

2) таблица цветов(обновляется редко, только когда добавляется новый цвет в систему)

```
 color_id, color_name
```

3) таблица соответствия цветов-товаров:

```
product_id, color_id - ни то ни другое не уникальное. Но и на том и на другом - индекс.
```

Заполняете так:

1. Вносите товар в таблицу товары. Получаете id: mysqli_insert_id()
2. Берете массив цветов $_POST['product_color'], **ПРОВЕРЯЕТЕ ЕГО НА XSS**
3. Заносите столько новых строк в таблицу соответствий, сколько у вас цветов для ДАННОГО товара

простейший случай:

```
foreach($_POST['product_color'] as $color){
   $sql = sprintf('insert into product_colors(product_id, color_id) values (%d,%d)',$product_id,$color);
}
```

Тогда select у вас строится по принципу

```
<option value="color_id">color_name</option>
```

Comment: как я понял в базу должно записаться примерно так "бело-зеленый","зеленый","черный" - так?

Comment: А это уже зависит от вашей фантазии.
В идеале - id+autoincrement, color_name
Но возможен вариант и 
r,g,b,color_name.

В моем примере - id,name, id будет автоматически присваивать новым цветам новую чиселку. 

Какая у вас задача?

Comment: у меня задача добавить новый товар в базу у которого есть несколько вариантов цветов, установить эти цвета в соответствующее поле.

Вывести варианты цветов товара на страничке данного товара 

У меня запись в базу идет так:

$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO products (product_title,product_kategory,product_sum,product_img,product_opisanie,product_color,product_code,articul_cod_partner,add_date) VALUES ('$product_title','$product_kategory','$product_sum','$product_img','$product_opisanie','".implode('"),("',$_POST['product_color'])."'','$product_code','$articul_cod_partner','$adddate')");

Comment: понимаю что не правильно, но что-то котел не варит после суток работы... 

Еще я не понял про вывод вариантов цветов select'том. 

Если честно ниразу еще не имел дело с foreach =/ в этом проекте первый раз столкнулся

Comment: Дополнил. Прочитайте про третью нормальную форму и, собственно, foreach. :)
Ну и, конечно, постарайтесь уйти от mysql_ в сторону, хотя бы, mysqli_

Comment: спасибо. простите только изучаю все.